# New Gaming System - Motherboard [Romania]

Tags: motherboard

I'm building a system to play the latest games at max settings at 1920x1080 and get as close to 30 FPS as possible within the budget.

The trouble is that the website I'm buying from is in Romanian, so using it depends on how patient you are with a few translations.

**Location:** Romania, Bucharest

**Site of choice:** dc-shop.ro ("Componente & Monitoare" from the homepage) / **EDIT:** Also using emag.ro (top-left "Oferta Produse" -> "PC, Periferice & Software")

---Part requirements--------

**Price limit:** 800 RON

**Overclocking:** No

**CPU Socket:** 1151

**GPU:** 1 x PCIe x16 (ideally the board layout would not have a long card hitting/covering anything on the board)

**Slots for:** 1 x wireless adapter

**Storage:** 1 x HDD SATA 2 & 1 x SSD SATA 3 (no RAID)

**Memory:** 2x 4GB DDR4

**USB:** front 2x 3.0 / back min 2x 3.0 / back total 6x 2.0/3.0

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Z170A gaming pro, because it's futureproof: supports DDR up to 3400 MHz, has good heat sinks and has everything you need & more, and fits well under your budget. The cheaper alternative for me would be H170 (still great).